# How to use JOIN in UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, join, sql

I am very weak at join and i need to know that how can i convert following query using joins. This Query is working fine with sub queries but i need to convert it and use it making joins.

```
update dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl 
set Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc='Changes from Baseline' 
where Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc='Increased Hours' 
and Stmt_Line_Item_Id 
in (select tmt_Line_Item_Ref_Id 
    from dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item 
    where Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id =
        (select Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id  
         from dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Type 
         where Stmt_Line_Item_Desc like 'ABOX/RBOX Amendment 18 and 20'))
```

Please if any body can help me.

Thanks

Comment: can you English your title please

Comment: @Daniel: This is my fault, wrong layout used. I edited the topic already, please delete your comments

Comment: whats weired about the heading. i just wanted that how can i convert this query using Joins

Comment: Why do you need to convert it? Is it broken? Running too slow? Homework?

Comment: yup as i m having lacs of records in each of the table and hence this is running very slow. can i have it using Joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following query uses joins to update your table but if it would be faster remains to be seen.

Could you post the query plan so we can have a look at that

```
update  dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl 
set     Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc = 'Changes from Baseline' 
from    dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl dtl
        inner join dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item li on li.tmt_Line_Item_Ref_Id = dtl.Stmt_Line_Item_Id
        inner join dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Type lit on lit.Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id = li.Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id
where   dtl.Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc='Increased Hours' 
        and lit.Stmt_Line_Item_Desc like 'ABOX/RBOX Amendment 18 and 20'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl 
set Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc='Changes from Baseline' 
where Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc='Increased Hours' 
and Stmt_Line_Item_Id 
in (select tmt_Line_Item_Ref_Id 
    from dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item Item
    JOIN dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Type Type
    on Type.Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id = Item.Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id
    and Type.Stmt_Line_Item_Desc like 'ABOX/RBOX Amendment 18 and 20')
```

or

```
update dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl 
set Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc = 'Changes from Baseline' 
from dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl Detail
JOIN dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item Item
on Item.tmt_Line_Item_Ref_Id = Detail.Stmt_Line_Item_Id
JOIN dbo.TFIN_Stmt_Line_Item_Type Type
on Type.Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id = Item.Stmt_Line_Item_Type_Id
and Type.Stmt_Line_Item_Desc like 'ABOX/RBOX Amendment 18 and 20')
where Detail.Stmt_Line_Item_Dtl_Desc = 'Increased Hours'
```